# JMS file transfer progress

Tags: java, file, jms, openmq

Is there any way of getting progress information for big file transfer over `jms` ?

I am using `openmq` and point to point messaging.

Comment: How large of a file are you sending that you need a status?  And since messaging is somewhat asynchonous, is there anyway you can fire and forget?

Comment: The files are about 100 mb. The legacy system uses FTP client to transfer file over network. When the transfer is completed (by sending special file), a script lunch import process. When all files are imported, they are marked as treated. The process is too tricky to handle. I would like to replace all this process by JMS point to point messaging